# Pandas will not input data into dataframe in the correct order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was initially trying to run the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

f = ['Austria', '11m/18d/19yyy', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 1, 'JVI Residences', 2, 1, 'Brief additional comments.']

test= pd.DataFrame(f, columns ={'Country' , 'Date of last observation' , 'ResRep/RTAC/RTC (Yes/No?)' ,
                                            'Available Facilities (Yes/No?)' , 'Funds Transferrable (Yes/No?)' ,
                                            'Local Flight Help (Yes/No?)' , 'Visa Help (Yes/No?)' , 
                                            'Local Support Rating 1 Great - 3 Bad' , 'Hotel Name' , 
                                            'Hotel Rating 1 Great - 3 Bad' ,
                                            'Travel Route Rating 1 Great - 3 Bad' , 'Additional Overall Comments'})
```

that kept resulting in the following error:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (12, 1), indices imply (12, 12)
```

So I attempted to correct that by putting brackets around F when creating the dataframe. However, this resulted in pandas returning a datframe with the column names out of order and the data in the categories it should not be in:

```
  Available Facilities (Yes/No?)  ...                     Country
0                        Austria  ...  Brief additional comments.

[1 rows x 12 columns]

Index(['Available Facilities (Yes/No?)', 'Hotel Name',
       'Local Support Rating 1 Great - 3 Bad', 'Additional Overall Comments',
       'Date of last observation', 'Local Flight Help (Yes/No?)',
       'ResRep/RTAC/RTC (Yes/No?)', 'Travel Route Rating 1 Great - 3 Bad',
       'Visa Help (Yes/No?)', 'Hotel Rating 1 Great - 3 Bad',
       'Funds Transferrable (Yes/No?)', 'Country'],
      dtype='object')
```

Can some one advise how to get my data to go into the dataframe I am trying to make and keep it in the order I want?

Comment: `columns` should be a list not dict

Comment: `pd.DataFrame([f], columns=your_columns_here)`

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given a `set` as the value of the parameter `columns`. Pandas will take the set and try to convert it to a list. But, as `set` is an unordered data structure, the order of yours column names could not be preserved while converting it from set to list. Simply, use a `list` instead of a `set`.